# xcode 4.2 shortcut keys 

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2

can anybody give idea to navigate in interface builder 
    from source code and also navigation shortcut to navigate 
    inside of interface builder in xcode 4.2?

thnx & regard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[XCode Keyboard Shortcuts](http://cloud.github.com/downloads/Machx/Xcode-Keyboard-Shortcuts/Xcode_Shortcuts.pdf)